# If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 + 2xyz$ so $4 + 4xyz \geq (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)$

Tags: inequality

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 + 2xyz$. 
I want to prove $2 + 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)$. By $AM-GM$ i have $2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \geq xy + xz + yz$ then if i proof that $2 \geq 1 + x + y +z +xyz$ i finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequality $2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq xy+xz+yz$ is weak in this case, because if $x=y=z=1$ then $2<1+x+y+z+xyz$.

Instead of it, just expand the right hand side of the inequality, and you will get:
$$4+4xyz \geq (1+x)(1+y)(1+z) = 1+x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+xyz$$
$$3+3xyz \geq x+y+z+xy+xz+yz$$
$$6+6xyz \geq 2x+2y+2z+2xy+2xz+2yz$$
$$3+3(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq 2x+2y+2z+2xy+2xz+2yz.$$
An now you can rewrite them as the sum of squares on the left hand side, which is always nonnegative.